# How to upload document files (pdf,doc) to firebase in react native expo

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload doc files from Expo CLI to my firebase storage in react native but it gives me a network error.

I use document picker to get file URI from storage and then I use this function to upload it to my firebase storage.

```js
const uploadDocuments = () => {
    let recievedDocs = [];
    document.map(async (item, index) => {
      var docName = user.uid + Math.floor(Math.random() * 127212);
      const response = await fetch(item.uri);
      const blob = await response.blob();
      var ref = firebase.storage().ref("postDocs/documents/" + docName);

      ref
        .put(blob)
        .then((res) => {
          ref
            .getDownloadURL()
            .then((url) => {
              recievedDocs.push(url);             
            })
            .catch((e) => {
              alert(e.message);
            });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          alert(e.message);
        });
    });
};
```

I also use this function to upload images to firebase storage from image picker and its work fine there but when I use this same function for docs file uri that I get from document picker to upload it gives me a network error

here is an error that I get.

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
> at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:383:16 in callTimers
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
> at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Comment: yeah it was path issue that i was getting in uri.
i have just edit that uri with prefix file:\\

here is the extra code

` if (result.type === "success") {
      if (Platform.OS === "android" && result.uri[0] === "/") {
        result.uri = `file://${result.uri}`;
        result.uri = result.uri.replace(/%/g, "%25");
      }
`